# Getting rare exceptions when trying to send a string through pipe

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have two different applications communicating with pipes. Most requests work fine, but from time to time, I get following exception when trying to send a string through pipe:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Pipe hasn't been connected yet.
```

With the following stack:

```
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.CheckWriteOperations()
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.Flush()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
```

Last line points to the line in client pipe code, I marked it with ">"

```
    using (var pipeClient =
        new NamedPipeClientStream("PipeName"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
            {
                pipeClient.Connect(20000);
                streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                streamWriter.WriteLine(dataToSend);
                pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
           >}
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.Error("ExceptionText");
        }
    }
```

On server, this is how pipes are being handled:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
                {
                        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                        string data;
                        while ((data = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                         //Process the data here...
                        }
                        pipeServer.Disconnect();
                }
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), `PipeStream.Flush()` isn't even supposed to do anything, yet it somehow fails? I'm confused about the whole situation.

What does it all mean? Does it try to dispose the pipe that somehow became disconnected in process?
If yes, what can I do about it?

Or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**:
According to [reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/Pipes/PipeStream.cs), during `PipeStream.Flush()` pipe state is checked. If state happens to be `WaitingToConnect`, it returns the exception I'm getting.

How can this happen though? If `pipeClient.Connect(20000);` happened without exceptions, then the state has to be different, whether it is `Connected`, `Broken` or something else.

Comment: See Source : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/Pipes/PipeStream.cs.  It does do checking and if the checking (CheckWriteOperations) fails you will get an exception.

Comment: By using Connect(20000) you opened the door to this failure mode.  That connect attempt can time out, it will throw a TimeoutException.  The *using* statement still does its job and disposes the StreamWriter.  Which also disposes its underlying Stream, kaboom.  Just do this other way around, first Connect() and then create the StreamWriter.

Comment: @HansPassant  Connect(20000) happens without exceptions though. If it did, I'd get logged exception about it.

Comment: No, it will not be logged.  The TimeoutException is *replaced* by the InvalidOperationException.  Standard trap in *finally* blocks that throw an exception, you can't see the original exception anymore.  Other than in the debugger output.  Just test this to see this for yourself by intentionally causing a timeout.

Comment: @HansPassant I guess that would explain my problem. Change your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it as correct.